# postgres grant on functions issue

Tags: postgresql

So I am having an issue that I wanted to clear up. I am granting access to a user in postgres, but I only want that user to be able to execute functions.

I have the following code:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA not_public TO test_id;            
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO test_id;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION testFunction TO web_reporting_id;
```

When this is ran, though, and I try to run the function under that user, I get a permissions error on the first table the function tries to read from.

I know some db languages you only need to grant permissions for the functions/procedures and not the underlying objects. In postgres, do I need to grant permissions on the tables too? Or do I need to update my grant scripts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, functions run with the privileges of the user calling them, so all SQL statements in them will be executed by that user.

You could define the function as `SECURITY DEFINER` to have it run with the privileges of the function owner, but then you must use the `SET` clause of `CREATE FUNCTION` to fix the `search_path` for the duration of the function execution [for security reasons](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/abusing-security-definer-functions/).

Also note that by default, everybody (`PUBLIC`) has execute privileges on functions, so you might want to revoke that.